# nhttp does not show the proper status

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

Many of the times our Domino http is making me tense.

Because of the various reasons, Please tell the proper solution for
this...

1. I started my both domino and Notes. After sometime I restarted my domino server. Now my nhttp is not getting started on my server. It is telling http is already running. But I have checked my Task manager and found that port 80 is occupied by nhttp. After I have end that process it is again restarted. Why is this happening?
2. Some of java programs run on server. When the JVM may crashed. That time I have no choice except restarting the server. Pleae tell is their any way to restart JVM. or Kill the nhttp.

Comment: Do you by chance have nhttp listed twice in your tasks list in notes.ini?

Comment: Which Domino release? 

The NHTTP task of your server might not have terminates correctly. How did you restart the server? Did you reboot the machine, or did you only restart the Domino server? Is it a server or a service process in Windows?

And how did you manage to crash the JVM?

Comment: No, show task is listed nhttp once.

Comment: I am using Domino 8.5.2 server. Exactly my nhttp task terminated abnormally. 'restart server' command restarts my server. No need of rebooting my windows. When the JVM crash I used to restart the server. But the some of the task will not be terminated. That time I manually click the close button.

Comment: This is not a programming question, so it belongs on ServerFault instead of StackOverflow.

Comment: Server is configured well. In our domino, whenever the JVM crash happened (It won't happen easily - run any java swing in agent[infinite loop]). That time we are not able to restart the http task

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the IIS-service isn't started, the HTTP-task will take and hold port 80.